# Writing a concluding paragraph

Tags: essay

How can I write a favorable conclusion paragraph? I know I could just summarize the main ideas of the essay, but are there any other ways to write a conclusion paragraph?

Comment: What do you mean by "favourable"?

Comment: @EDL Ellara has clearly stated that she knows one way of writing a "conclusion paragraph" (namely "summarizing the main ideas"). She now wants to learn how to write a "favourable conclusion paragraph". Your edit to the question has changed Ellara's intent and removed her actualy question. Why don't you ask for clarification before you change a question in a way that the asker might not have intended?

Comment: Ellara, if you are unhappy with the edits by EDL, you can undo them by clicking on the link that says "edited x hours ago" above EDL's profile image, or you can improve on EDL's edit by clicking on "Edit" under the text of your question. I think you will get better help if you clarify your question. Maybe you could add some information about the type of essay your write (for school, for uni, for a college admission, ...), what the topic of the essay is, and what you would like to do in the conclusion but have trouble with. The more details we have, the more precise can our answers be.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to summarize the earlier points.

You want to talk about their *implications*, what this means "looking forward".

Depending on the discussion. If we are discussing symptoms of a problem, what your conclusions suggest is a route to alleviating the problem.

If we are discussing a new technology, what your conclusions suggest is a route toward exploiting the new technology, or what in the future the new technology will change.

In general devote a paragraph to the future *implications* of your conclusions.

Comment: Your statement that one doesn't summarize the earlier points in the conclusion of an essay is false. The convention (and what teachers expect) is that the conclusion begins with a repetition of the thesis statement, followed by a summary of the main points, and ends with the conclusions drawn from the question and the arguments. See e.g.: https://libguides.newcastle.edu.au/how-to-write-an-essay/conclusion (University of Newcastle). An essay for school is shorter than an academit essay, nevertheless it should also end with a summary of the thesis and main points before coming to the conclusion.

Comment: The questioner says they know that, and asks if there is any other way. There is another way. In fact, it is what we routinely use in academic papers; I've written several published academic papers and I've read hundreds of them.

Comment: The common guidelines for the discussion section in academic journals is to begin the discussion by repeating the main idea for performing the present study and briefly summarizing the research findings. One random example: "IV. A. 8. Discussion ... For experimental studies, it is useful to begin the discussion by **summarizing briefly the main findings** ..." (International Committee of Medical Journal Editors, "Uniform requirements for manuscripts submitted to biomedical journals", https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3142758/) The guidelines in other fields are similar.

Comment: DeGruyter, one of the largest scientific publishers, recommends: "4.8 Conclusion ... **Sum up what you have shown in your study** and indicate possible applications and extensions." (https://blog.degruyter.com/how-to-write-a-good-research-paper/) —— I have now provided three reputable sources that recommend to begin the conclusion with a summary of the preceding arguments or findings. Please provide sources other than your personal practices that explicitly recommend not to summarize one's earlier points. Otherwise I have to assume that you just follow bad practices...

Comment: @Ben "indicate possible applications and extensions." The comment section is not a venue for debate or argument. You've said your piece. The questioner can read your comments and access your links. Or write your own answer. I will flag any further comments you make for moderation.

Answer (score 0):

As someone who has to write essays for school conclusions are difficult at times. You could write a joke or heartfelt statement. I sometimes like to say “Why do we have to write so much? We can already speak (insert any language).”

Answer (score 0):

As @amadeus answered, just recapitulating what you’ve already stated isn’t worth all that much. And by the way, much of what gets you credit for “writing for the teacher” is really crippling when you’re truly engaged in writing something that actually matters to you, as when you’re “writing for readers who count in the real world.”

I encourage writers to avoid misinterpreting the word *conclusion*. Don’t read it to mean ending—which, admittedly, **could** call for rehashing what you should by that point have already presented adequately. No, read it to mean inferences… what new thoughts follow from all that you had already stated. It shouldn’t be the conclusion **of** those statements, but the conclusions **from** them. When writers do that, their readers find that portion worth reading.